# convert jquery condition is(':checked') into boolean array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick and dirty. I want check if all children checkbox are checked, so I would convert

```
$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').is(':checked')
```

into boolean array, in order to check it in a `if` condition with `every()` method.
I have tryied `every()`,`toArray()`,`makeArray` and any combination fo them.
Which is the rigth way?

Comment: @Vohuman Can you please show?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: "Check if all children checkboxes are checked" --- "convert into boolean array" This is a clear example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
var arr = $(this).parent().find(':checkbox').map(function() {
    return this.checked;
}).get();
```

That'll get the bool array, if you just want to see if all the children are checked:

```
var areAllChecked = $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length === 0;
```

Comment: @Vohuman -- Realized that after re-reading - edited.

Comment: [Put the `get` immediately after the `find`, then replace `map` with `every`, and you're spot on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26509036/356541).

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check whether all are checked then test for if any are not checked and then negate it like

```
!$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').is(':not(:checked)')
```

Comment: very elegant solution to check if all children are selected. I choose the other answer because fit better with the title.

Answer (score 1):

> I want check if all children checkbox are checked

I suppose you can use this syntax to accomplish that, rather than involving an array of booleans.

```
var allAreChecked = ($(this).parent().find(':checkbox').not(':checked').length === 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation on [tymeJV's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26508927/356541) answer:

```
$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').get().every(function(el){ return el.checked });
```

This simply `get`s the underlying array of element and uses `every` directly on that array to check the relevant property. It will return false is any checkbox fails `this.checked`.

Demo:

```js
function allChecked(){
  return $(this).parent().find(':checkbox').get().every(function(el){
    return el.checked 
  });
}

$('button').on('click', function(){ alert( allChecked.call(this) ) })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<button>All checked?</button>
```